# facebook graph api returning empty json

Tags: facebook, api

Using the link to my events automatically generated in the docs here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (Events: https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=...), I can get a json object populated with the events I'm RSVP'ed to.

When I request them from my app (having gotten an access token authorized to view user_events), I get back an empty json object.

My app can get back a populated friends list.  I also can't get back a populated list of photo albums.

Anybody got a guess for what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions problem, has your access token definitely got the user_events permission? Check with a call to `/me/permissions`
You can also use the debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (put the access token in there) and it will tell you what permissions the token was granted

Comment: I did have the user_events permission set correctly.  When I removed it, I would get a user permissions error rather than an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

My app events are also an empry array. I fetch them via graph api.

I guess it is because I created them on behalf of the user. Facebook displays (on the event page itself) as admins the user AND the app, which made me assume, both are owner/creator. The event array though lists only the app user (under the key #creator').

Confusing.

Comment: Did you request the user_events permission from the user?